# Babel not working even in English mode

Tags: miktex, babel

I recently installed MikTeX 4.0.1 running under Windows 10 64-bit.
The problem: Cannot get `babel` package to work, even for English. I have tried basically everything imaginable (short of removing entire Miktex installation) but to no avail. Any help greatly appreciated!

Minimal example is

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{babel}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
This is an example.
\end{document}
```

and produces the following error when run under PDFLATEX:

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.12) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.1.11)
****** SKIP LINES****

! Undefined control sequence.
l.40 \ProvidesLanguage
{english}

Comment: Is your miktex fully up to date? And please don't skip lines from the log they can often contain interesting debugging clues if you know what to look for

Comment: I believe MikTeX is fully up to date (I installed it last month and used Updates in MikTeX console). But babel package is most probably outdated. The problem is that I do not know how to convince MikTeX to update the babel package. Here are some more lines from the log file  (I can show only a few lines at a time): 

LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 3
L3 programming layer <2020-12-07> xparse <2020-03-03>
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/EMTEX/TEXINPUT/BABEL\babel.sty"
Package: babel 1999/09/09 v3.6Z The Babel package

File: babel.def 1999/09/09 v3.6Z Babel common definitions

Comment: I think I have finally found the solution-- It seems the EMTEX folder was the culprit. After I deleted the babel subfolder in EMTEX/TEXINPUT  it now seems to work. 
It is strange though that MikTeX was not able to do this by itself-- I added once EMTEX folder to MikTeX directories but  then removed it from MikTeX directories and updated every possible thing in MikTeX.....

Thanks for your assistance, it was really helpful!